# Echo PHP Variable in XML and Post value to webservice

Tags: php, xml

I need to publish PHP variable values on SOAP-based web service some how I am not able to convert PHP POST values in XML elements.

How can I get POST variable, say `abc`, in `sName` element?

My code in PHP

```
    <?php

    //session_start();

    $server_name= abc;

   $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
  <createtest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <sA>ADD</sA>
  <sType>service</sType>
  <sName>"$server_name"</sName>
  </createtest>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>';


     $headers = array(
     "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
     "Host: http://example.com",
     "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
     "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/createtest"
      );

    url = 'http://example.com';  // WSDL web service url for request 
    method/function
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP 
    request
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
     ?>
```

Comment: You are using single quotes round the XML content, this means that variable substitutions will not be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around abc, when you define the variable as a string:

```
$server_name = "abc";
```

And you could also put the variable in the string like this to make it easier to understand it as a variable in such a long string:

```
   $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
  <createtest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <sA>ADD</sA>
  <sType>service</sType>
  <sName>'.$server_name.'</sName>
  </createtest>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>';
```

Comment: I also tried that but its throw an error (Error: A device attached to the system is not functioning)  so Not sure what need to change ....

Comment: Well, the error explains what you have to do. And it seems like that is a different question than you posted. Can you update your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It working perfectly fine ... Thanks you for your Help ....